# Recursive call in Python shows non-empty list in debug but becomes 'None' type when passed into function

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, recursion

A noob question: I'm implementing merge sort for a list in python. However, I keep getting an issue at one of the last steps in the execution, where I'm passing 3 lists into a function and two of them are appearing as being of type 'None' even though in the debugger they show up with the intended values.

To be honest, I need to really dive deep into recursion (the debugger is great for that, I just learned) because that has been a stumbling block for me as a student. However, being that the assignment is due at midnight (this is one part out of a large problem set), I don't have time to go deep and experiment tonight, though I will in the near future.

Here is my code:

```
def swap(_a, _b):
    if _a <= _b:
        return (_a, _b)
    else:
        return (_b, _a)


def merge(*args):
    print("DEBUG: merge() reachable")
    B, C, A = args[0], args[1], args[2]
    i, j, k = 0, 0, 0

    while i < len(B) and j < len(C):
        if B[i] <= C[j]:
            A[k] = B[i];
            i += 1
        else:
            A[k] = C[j];
            j += 1
        k += 1
    if i == len(B):
        A[k:] = C[j:]
    else:
        A[k:] = B[i:]

    #print("A is ", A)
    return(A)

def merge_sort(A):
    if len(A) <= 2:
        return (swap(A[0], A[1]))
    else:
        ln = len(A) // 2
        B, C = A[:ln], A[ln:]
        merge(merge_sort(B), merge_sort(C), A)

def main():
    # merge([5, 7, 9, 11], [2, 4, 5, 7], [0 for i in range(8)])
    merge_sort([3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here are snips of the code, the debug, and the error message I get: https://ibb.co/w76tsJv https://ibb.co/92rQwNM https://ibb.co/qFKfC8p.

Here is a repl: https://repl.it/repls/WholeRecentTheory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function

```py
def merge_sort(A):
    if len(A) <= 2:
        return (swap(A[0], A[1]))
    else:
        ln = len(A) // 2
        B, C = A[:ln], A[ln:]
        merge(merge_sort(B), merge_sort(C), A)
```

does not return anything in the second branch, which means the last line evaluates to `merge(None, None, A)`. Replace the last line with 
`return merge(merge_sort(B), merge_sort(C), A)` and your code works as you intended.